# How to dynamically schedule a function to run at specified time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a Iot project. In my case, user can schedule a actuator command to run on specified time.( say on 08/06/2021 at 08.05 AM). This will be stored in mongodb database as a date variable. My requirement is to send an MQTT publish message to actuator at that specified time. Note that, this scheduling is not like interval scheduling. Each schedule will run exactly one time. I also need to edit the scheduled date time.

There is one way to achieve this. Each time user schedule a command, I can run a setTimeout function. But this is not a good practice and editing the schedule is difficult. So please help me to find a optimal solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may check existing cron like packages

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: How can I use that for edit exiting schedule? If I need to keep track of newly created cron or schedule object, how can I do that?

Comment: node-cron have a task.destroy(); function, just delete and recreate the task ?
node-schedule of @James Mudd comment also have a job.reschedule(spec) function